# Assigning to Typename Array Class C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an array wrapper class for a project. Everything is working ok, except I'm not able to assign values ( array[i] = value; ) that already exist in the array, I keep getting "expression must be a modifyable lvalue". I tried to overload the assignment operator but had no luck.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline bool operator==(const T left, const T right)
{
    return &left == &right;
}

template <typename T>
class TArray {

    std::vector<T> data;

public:

    TArray() { }

    void Reserve(unsigned int space)
    {
        if (space == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        data.reserve(space);
    }

    /**
    * Adds a value
    */
    void Add(T value)
    {
        data.push_back(value);
    }

    /**
    * Adds the value if it does not already exist
    */
    void AddUnique(T value)
    {
        if (Contains(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        Add(value);
    }

    /**
    * Removes the first value in the array matching the value
    */
    void Remove(T value)
    {
        std::vector<T>::iterator itr = std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), value);
        if (itr != data.end())
        {
            data.erase(itr);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Removes all matching the type
    */
    void RemoveAllMatching(T value)
    {
        for (int i = data.size(); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (data[i] == value)
            {
                data.erase(i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Removes value at index
    */
    void RemoveAtIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index > data.size() - 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        data.erase(index);
    }

    /**
    * Returns true if the array contains the object
    */
    bool Contains(T value)
    {
        for (T v : data)
        {
            if (v == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the number of the same value
    */
    int ContainsQuantity(T value)
    {
        int quantity = 0;

        for (T v : data)
        {
            if (v == value)
            {
                ++quantity;
            }
        }

        return quantity;
    }

    void Clear() { data.clear(); }

    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin() const { return data.begin(); }

    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end() const { return data.end(); }

    int Size() { return data.size(); }

    T operator[](int index) { return data[index]; }
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

You apply the `[]` operator.
Then you attempt to assign to what that returns.

What it returns is a copy of `T`, because of `T operator[](int index) { return data[index]; }`.

You'd have to return a reference.

As kindly pointed out by HolyBlack Cat, it would be almost needed to also have

> a second `operator[]` that's `const` and returns `const T &`

because

> It just allows you to call `[]` on const objects/references to read the values.

E.g. if you define a const version of what you are implementing.

Comment: One also needs a second `operator[]` that's `const` and returns `const T &`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is that needed for what OP describes to be trying? Then I missed something. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Not for what they're trying to do, but in general. I'm not arguing with the answer.

Comment: You are probably right. Could you give an example of what that is needed for? Because I admit that I don't see an often-needed usecase right now. @HolyBlackCat Then I could mention/recommend it with an example.

Comment: It just allows you to call `[]` on const objects/references to read the values.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was focusing on non-const arrays.

Comment: Ahh, that seemed to work!

```const T operator[](int index) const { return data[index]; }
 T& operator[](int index) { return data[index]; } ```

One more question: For the comparison operator, I think it's only checking for pointer location. Is there a way to get it to check for the value of certain types like int, float, bool etc?

Comment: Happy to help. :-) For the one more question please create a new post.

Comment: @Jenova The return type of the const version should be `const T &`.